# Deploying app to Azure Virtual Machine scale set

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-vm-scale-set

I have a question about deploying app to azure virtual scale set.
I use an instruction from [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/05/15/deploying-applications-to-azure-vm-scale-sets/) blog.

My problem is with release an image to azure and more specifically with Deployment Inputs in task "Build immutable image".

[Screen with my Deployment Inputs section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYDZo.png)

And when I try to Release it I have an error:

```
 [error]Error happened while `initializing task: Not found any file matching pattern: d:\a\r1\a\Proj\ under root folder: d:\a\r1\a..`
```

How should the correct paths look?
Setting as in the instructions from the blog results in the same error.
What is this: "d:\a\r1\a\"?

EDIT:

Ok. I have dealt with this problem. 
It should be:
Deployment Package  `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Proj/drop`
Deployment script  `Deploy/ubuntu/deployNodejsApp.sh`

But the there is a second one.
In step "Buil immutable image" I have an error:

```
2017-08-18T13:34:56.6852114Z ##[error]Error: d:\a\_temp\1503062745199\packer\packer.exe failed with return code: 1
2017-08-18T13:34:56.6992118Z ##[section]Finishing: Build immutable image
```

and it does not move on to the next step: Azure powershell script.

In my azure storage account I have new vhd file, but when I used it in template to create scale set I still have information `Continuous Delivery is currently not supported on Virtual machine scale sets which use OS images from gallery. Choose a virtual machine scale set which uses a custom image.`

Comment: Add variable system.debug to release definition and set it to true, then create a new release, then post the detail log here. On the other hand, do you get the error of Continuous Delivery is currently not supported... in azure portal when configure Continuous delivery?

Answer (score 0):

I am the writer of the blog post. Can you please set the syste.debug to true and share the logs?

blog.devmatter.com/enabling-verbose-output-in-team-foundation-build-logs/

There are two ways to deploy to a VM Scale Set. One is by using immutable VHD (which the blog talks about) and other is by using custom script extension.

In the immutable VHD approach there are two requirements:
 - The VHD image should be contained in a storage account which is in the same location as the VM Scale Set is created in
 - The VM Scale that you are trying to update must have been created by using a custom VHD and not a platform image. To use immutable VHD approach for updating VMSS you can create a VMSS by using the following blog posts:

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-linux-customimage-autoscale

We are working on supporting VMSS which were created by using platform image and the update should be out soon. This new approach will use custom script extension to help you update your apps.
For VSTS related issues you can also post here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html

Comment: is there an example provided using custom script with azure devops? Immutable though good does not meet out requirements as we have frequent deployment. 20 min pre deployment is not feasible.