# deploying web application to azure scaleset using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-vm-scale-set

Is there a better way to deploy a web application (hosted on IIS windows) to Azure Scaleset using Azure DevOps other than Immutable image? I assume for every deployment if the pipeline needs to create an image it would take too much time to create the image and deploy especially if there is a need to deploy a hot fix.

has any one tried if deployment group works with azure Scaleset?

Comment: The answer in this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45756263/deploying-app-to-azure-virtual-machine-scale-set/45816808#45816808) mentions:There are two ways to deploy to a VM Scale Set. One is by using immutable VHD (which the blog talks about) and other is by using custom script extension. In addition, you can also refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069973/azure-virtual-machine-scale-set-vsts-deployment-group)

Comment: I did see this regarding Deployment group but no conclusive way to say it work in the discussion

Comment: I think you have started deploying web application to azure scaleset with custom script extension.

Comment: how do I use custom script extension with Azure Devops. What are steps in my release definition?

Answer (score 0):

Besides using immutable images, another method is deploying web application to azure scaleset using custom script extension.

Here are tutorials about installing applications in virtual machine scale sets with the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-install-apps-cli) or [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-install-apps-powershell).

This tutorial shows how to:

- Automatically install applications to your scale set
- Use the Azure Custom Script Extension
- Update a running application on a scale set

You can refer to these tutorials for details.

Comment: Can you give me a flow how this will tie in with Azure Devop in the release definition ? What steps should I be doing. A high level descriptions would be helpfull